# How to use Node -r flag inside npm scripts on Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-web-app-service

I am running a node site on an Azure App Service but it won't start with the following line in my package.json scripts.

```
   "scripts": {
        ...
        "serve": "node -r dotenv-azure/config dist/server.js",
        ...
    },
```

The -r flag is required to preload environment variables using dotenv-azure, as per their own instructions... https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-azure

it works absolutely fine on localhost (Windows), it loads the config before starting the server. On Azure App service (windows) however it fails to start the server and I get a 503 error after starting it.

I have tried switching on application logging but because it can't even start the server I get nothing in the logs.

Comment: Because you are using windows webapp, I thought of hosting the nodejs project on `iis`, so I thought of using `httpplatformhandler` in the `web.config` file for processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After add `httpplatformhandler` in `web.config` file, it works for me. You can [download my sample code from github](https://github.com/Jason446620/dotenv-azuredemo). You will find my `web.config` file.

## Test Steps：

**1. Create a sample code.**

[image]

**2. Create `.env` file.**

[image]

**3. Test result in local.**

[image]

**4. Deploy by git.**

[image]

After deployed, it also has some error, we should add `web.config` to solve it.

**After add `web.config` file ( With `httpplatformhandler`):**

[image]